# strings.Contains in switch-case GoLang

Tags: string, go, switch-statement, contains

Is it possible to use strings.Contains in switch case?
something like:

```
func function(str string){
    switch str {
    case "str1":
        ...
    case strings.Contains("test"):
        ...
    default:
        ...
    }
}
```

Edit: its an example, thats not the real case I need it for. Im filtering many results and I want all results that contains X and I also have cases that I need to fully match.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "testString"
    switch {
    case strings.Contains(str, "test"):
        fmt.Println(true)
    default:
        fmt.Println(false)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_2fMd-3kE-r

`switch` without argument is like `switch true`.

Comment: I also have some strings that I need to full match (case "testString":) in the same switch-case use, but if there is not a way to do so I will probably use your example.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a switch for this boolean output?

Use the following inbuilt function.

`func strings.Contains(s string, substr string) bool`

Comment: its an example, that not the real case I need it for. Im filtering many results and I want all results that contains X